# How to change the size of a Writeablebitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

I'm trying to embedd my XNA game into my WPF application.

To do so, I get the screen pixels of my XNA game, then copy it on a WriteableBitmap, that way:

```
 em_renderTarget2D.GetData(em_bytes);
 WriteableBitmap.Lock();
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(em_bytes, 0, WriteableBitmap.BackBuffer, em_bytes.Length);
 WriteableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, em_sizeViewport.X, em_sizeViewport.Y));
 WriteableBitmap.Unlock();
```

Then I get the bitmap on my WPF app and display it.

Problem is, I want to be able to resize the bitmap when the game is running (when the client resizes the app for example).

So I redefines the m_bytes, the rendertarget, ... and I create a new writeablebitmap:

```
WriteableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(em_sizeViewport.X, em_sizeViewport.Y, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr565, null);
```

The problem is, when I resize my app, the image becomes all black...
Where could the problem come from?
Even if the new width and the new height are the same as before, the image is also black.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the library https://github.com/reneschulte/WriteableBitmapEx

```
var resized = writeableBmp.Resize(200, 300, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
```

Comment: FYI - Link is broken.